# How do I say "get real" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "get real" in German? I'd like to say it in this context:

> A: Are you my girlfriend?
>   B: Get real!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Komm mal klar.

Oder:

> Träum weiter.

Answer (score 7):

With reference to "real(ity)", by assuming that the recipient is dreaming:

- »Träum weiter!«
- »Hör auf zu träumen!«
- »Du träumst wohl?«

Teenage slang:

- »Komm mal klar!«

Comment: Funny: That’s basically what I posted at almost exactly the same time.

Comment: @K.Stm: Yeah, I noticed it too after submitting my answer :D

Comment: Best two answers IMO ;)

Comment: "Komm mal klar" ist wohl nur im Norden üblich? Habe das hier zwischen Neckar und Donau noch nie gehört. Da würde es wohl eher "Schpinscht etzt?" heißen ....

Comment: @Ingo Ich hänge hart am Neckar ab und bring’ das ständig!

Answer (score 1):

"Werde erwachsen!"

manchmal auch "sei/werde vernünftig"

Answer (score 1):

I'll add

> Wach auf!

for the adult, serious discussions and

> Sei realistsich/ehrlich.

for adult, but not as deep discussions.